# Confusion about nested routes in Rails 3, specifically autogenerated paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

For each species, I have many datasets. For each dataset, I have many phenotypes. The datasets have names which, within a species, are primary keys. The species, too, have string primary keys (e.g., Hs for Homo sapiens). So, I want to be able to specify a phenotype as follows:

```
/species/Hs/mcgary/1
```

where mcgary is the name (slug) of the phenotype set.

I understand that I can get this kind of result by putting the following lines in my routes.rb file:

```
match "/species/:species_id/:dataset(/:id/:action)" => 'phenotypes'
match "/species/:species_id/:dataset/:id" => 'phenotypes#show'
```

Phenotypes is the phenotype controller. Species has a controller, but Dataset does not -- its functions are handled by Species' and Phenotype's controllers.)

Unfortunately, that doesn't guarantee that the paths will work, e.g., `edit_species_dataset_phenotype_path`. I'm not quite sure how to write that instruction in routes.rb. One possibility is to have, in addition to the match instructions, the following:

```
resources :species do
  resources :dataset do
    resources :phenotypes
  end
end
```

and just set up a redirect. But that's awkward. Is there some way I can use the match notation to get the paths working? Love the new routes, but wish the documentation had some full examples in it.

I also notice that if I do something like edit_species_dataset_path(species, dataset), I can get the `/species/:species_id/:phenotype_set_id` route format -- but I'm not sure how to get it to use :abbrev on Species instead, other than to type species.abbrev every time. Is there a way to tell it to use that column by default, instead of id?

Many thanks. (And yes, I realize nested routes like this get awkward. I'm okay with that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an imperfect solution, which is the `:path` option on `resources()`.

```
resources :species do
  resources :datasets do
    resources :phenotypes, :path => ""
  end
end
```

This gives me a slight variation on the routes I had wanted, and three controllers instead of two, which is not ideal -- but importantly, it works.

My paths are now of the form /species/Hs/datasets/mcgary/1 (for phenotype 1).

I also had to write some helper methods in `ApplicationHelper`. These make it a bit easier to have triply-nested resources.

```
def phenotype_path(phenotype, dataset=nil, species=nil)
  dataset ||= phenotype.dataset
  species ||= phenotype.species
  File.join(phenotypes_path(dataset, species), phenotype.id.to_s)
end

def phenotypes_path(dataset, species=nil)
  species ||= dataset.species
  File.join(species_path(species.abbrev), "datasets", dataset.name)
end

def edit_phenotype_path(phenotype, dataset=nil, species=nil)
  File.join(phenotype_path(phenotype,dataset,species), "edit")
end

def new_phenotype_path(dataset, species=nil)
  File.join(phenotypes_path(dataset, species), "new")
end

alias :dataset_path :phenotypes_path

def edit_dataset_path(dataset, species=nil)
  File.join(dataset_path(dataset, species), "edit")
end

def dataset_path(dataset, species=nil)
  species ||= dataset.species
  File.join(species_path(species.abbrev), "datasets", dataset.name)
end

def datasets_path(species)
  species_datasets_path(species.abbrev)
end
```

Unfortunately, these paths sometimes seem to conflict with the autogenerated paths. I'm not sure which module holds those paths, so it's difficult to rewrite them.

The other issue is that I can't quite figure out how to do species_path(species) and have it use the abbreviation. Instead, I have to do species_path(species.abbrev).